# Return zero if no results using COUNT-GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate

Trying to create a quarterly report using SQL which shows the number of occurrences of a particular crime (i.e. Breaking and Entering) broken down into months.  If that particular crime did not occur in a particular month, I want it to display as zero.  The SQL statement is only using one table and not joined to any other tables.

I have tried using a CASE statement without any positive results.

**CASE COUNT(DATE_OCCU)>=0 THEN 0 ELSE COUNT(DATE_OCCU) END AS QUANTITY**

```
select 
    datename(month,date_occu) as MonthName, 
    datepart(mm,date_occu) as MonthNumber,
    count(date_occu) as Quantity

from crimes.rms4gis.dbo.tmprms4gisall 
where datediff(mm,date_occu,getdate()) between 1 and 3 and agency='WCSO' and 
offense='DEATH INVESTIGATION' 

group by MonthName, MonthNumber
order by MonthNumber
```

The output is showing as follows

```
MonthName  |  MonthNumber  |  Quantity
______________________________________
May        |       5       |     1
June       |       6       |     3
```

I would like to show the results as follows...

```
MonthName  |  MonthNumber  |  Quantity
______________________________________
April      |       4       |     0
May        |       5       |     1
June       |       6       |     3
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Somewhat new at SQL.

J Garrido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have some data in the table for the months you want, you can switch to conditional aggregation:

```
select datename(month, date_occu) as MonthName, 
       datepart(month, date_occu) as MonthNumber,
       sum(case when agency = 'WCSO' and offense = 'DEATH INVESTIGATION' then 1 else 0 end) as Quantity
from crimes.rms4gis.dbo.tmprms4gisall 
where datediff(month, date_occu, getdate()) between 1 and 3 
group by datename(month, date_occu), datepart(month, date_occu)
order by MonthNumber;
```

There are other methods that involve generating the three months involved.  However, that requires a somewhat more complex query.  The above is a simple solution that should work in this -- and many other -- situations.

Comment: I don't think you can assume that. At least during the first day of the month you dont have any cases

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . The question is phrased as "If that particular crime did not occur in a particular month, I want it to display as zero."  The current month is not being considered by the query (`1 and 3`, not `0 and 3`).  There should be data in the table, even if not for the particular crime.

Comment: You are right. But some day society will evolve, and we will have months without crimes  :finger_crossed:

Answer (score 0):

If there are no rows from April, no groups will be created. 
If you want to include ‘missing months’, you have to supply the list of months and perform an outer join to your table so that all months will be returned.
You did not specify which engine you are using, so I can’t offer a full solution. You can create a Months table with 12 rows and join to that, or use the VALUES row constructor on the fly, something along the lines of :

... FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3) ...)  as M (month) LEFT OUTER JOIN yourtable as x on m.month = x.datepart....

HTH 
(sent from mobile)